# How do I insert into or update an RBTree from rbtree-rs?

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm having trouble understanding how to idiomatically find and append to or create a new vector if the value is part of a data structure, in this case a Red Black tree.

I'm using [this Red Black Tree implementation](https://github.com/tickbh/rbtree-rs) and the plan is to grab a mutable reference to the value which I will append to if it exists (not `None`) and create a new vector and move it to the `RBTree` if there is no value for the key. My code looks like this, slightly altered for brevity so excuse any careless errors:

```
struct Obj {
    tree: RBTree<i32, Vec<String>>,
}

let mut obj = Obj {
    tree: RBTree::new(),
};

let k = 5;
let v = "whatever";

match obj.tree.get_mut(k) {
    None => {
        let mut vec: Vec<Node> = Vec::new();
        vec.push(v);
        book.tree.insert(k, vec);
    }
    Some(vec) => vec.push(v),
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting a mutable reference to the tree when I check for existence because if it does exist, I want to mutate it by appending to the vector. However, if it does not exist, I want to insert a new node which tries to do a mutable borrow so I get a "second mutable borrow occurs here" on this line `book.tree.insert(k, vec);`.

I would love some insight into how to perform this find or create so that it compiles and is thread safe. I guess it's also possible the library I'm using has problems. Not yet qualified to comment on that.

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Comment: *so excuse any careless errors* — even better, you can take the time to produce a working [MCVE] and avoid having any careless errors in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases the workaround is to move the mutating code outside of `get_mut()`'s scope.

```
let needs_insert = match obj.tree.get_mut(k) {
    None => true,
    Some(vec) => {
        vec.push(v); 
        false
    }
};

if needs_insert {
    book.tree.insert(k, vec![v]);
}
```